# jquery window resize not working in requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, requirejs

I'm totally new to requirejs and started using it in my project. I have one problem when i use window resize event its not firing.
Here, i have added my code. Please help me out from this issue.

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
    $(function() {
      set_screen();
    });
    function set_screen(){
            var heroBannerHeight = $('#hero-banner').innerHeight(),
                heroCaptionHeight = $('#hero-banner .slider-caption').innerHeight();

            if(heroBannerHeight > heroCaptionHeight){
                $('#hero-banner, #hero-banner .slider-caption').css({'height':heroBannerHeight});
                $('#hero-banner').removeClass('large-description');
            } else {
                $('#hero-banner, #hero-banner .slider-caption').css({'height':heroCaptionHeight});
                $('#hero-banner').addClass('large-description');
            }

        }

        $(window).on("resize", function(event) {
            set_screen();
        });
    });
```

Comment: instantiate the function after you declare it

Comment: give me one example @madalinivascu

Comment: place your html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
    function set_screen(){
            var heroBannerHeight = $('#hero-banner').innerHeight(),
                heroCaptionHeight = $('#hero-banner .slider-caption').innerHeight();

            if(heroBannerHeight > heroCaptionHeight){
                $('#hero-banner, #hero-banner .slider-caption').css({'height':heroBannerHeight});
                $('#hero-banner').removeClass('large-description');
            } else {
                $('#hero-banner, #hero-banner .slider-caption').css({'height':heroCaptionHeight});
                $('#hero-banner').addClass('large-description');
            }

        }
       $(function() {
         set_screen();
         $(window).on("resize", function(event) {
            set_screen();
         });
       });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks @madalinivascu . But still having one problem. Condition not firing properly

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. Now its coming fine. Thanks @madalinivascu.